# filtering data frame based on other column and the number of related non zero value

Tags: r

suppose I have following data frame named `df`:

```
df<- data.frame("id" = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5),
                "relation" =c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2), 
                "salary" =c(20,10,0,30,0,0,10,0,0,40,45,42,15,0))
```

I want to extract two data frames such that if a household is two-earner or one-earner. those household who their members have at least two non zero salary are considered as two-earner, but those who have just one non zero salary are one- earner.
my expected output would be like this:

```
one-earner : 
 id relation salary
1  2        1     30
2  2        2      0
3  2        3      0
4  3        1     10
5  3        2      0
6  3        3      0
7  5        1     15
8  5        2      0

two-earner:
id relation salary
1  1        1     20
2  1        2     10
3  1        3      0
4  4        1     40
5  4        2     45
6  4        3     42
```

I tried by the code below but I do not know how to specify household with different non zero salary number:

```
two_earner <- df %>%
  group_by(address) %>%
  filter(all(salary >=2 ))

one_earner <- df %>%
  group_by(address) %>%
  filter(all(salary ==1 ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the case if `mean(salary > 0) > 1/2`.

```
> split(df, with(df, ave(salary, id, FUN=\(x) mean(x > 0) > 1/2))) |>
+   setNames(c('one', 'two'))
$one
   id relation salary
4   2        1     30
5   2        2      0
6   2        3      0
7   3        1     10
8   3        2      0
9   3        3      0
13  5        1     15
14  5        2      0

$two
   id relation salary
1   1        1     20
2   1        2     10
3   1        3      0
10  4        1     40
11  4        2     45
12  4        3     42
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
5), relation = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2), salary = c(20, 
10, 0, 30, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 40, 45, 42, 15, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: how can modify your code so that I have two distinct data frame?

Comment: you can pipe it in `|> list2env(.GlobalEnv)`.

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(group = ifelse(sum(salary > 0) >= 2, "two-earners", "one-earner"), .by = id) |>
  split(~ group)
```

I prefer to use base R `split` over dplyr `group_split()` because the former returns the names of the groups.

**Output**

This returns a named list:

```
$`one-earner`
   id relation salary      group
4   2        1     30 one-earner
5   2        2      0 one-earner
6   2        3      0 one-earner
7   3        1     10 one-earner
8   3        2      0 one-earner
9   3        3      0 one-earner
13  5        1     15 one-earner
14  5        2      0 one-earner

$`two-earners`
   id relation salary       group
1   1        1     20 two-earners
2   1        2     10 two-earners
3   1        3      0 two-earners
10  4        1     40 two-earners
11  4        2     45 two-earners
12  4        3     42 two-earners
```